# How to play back in-memory sound via MediaPlayer in Java/JavaFX

Tags: java, media-player, javafx-2

The API reference says `javafx.scene.media` supports playback sound from URLs. In my case, the sound file is:

1. completely in memory (in a byte-array), or
2. downloaded on-the-fly into memory

It must not be saved to a local file, but I want to play it back via `MediaPlayer`.

How can I create a URL of an in-memory sound byte-array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing mp3 files in JavaFx from input stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539814/playing-mp3-files-in-javafx-from-input-stream)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry you can't , because:

> Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URLs are supported.

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#constructor_detail)

Comment: I know what does the API say, I also wrote it in my question, however what I need is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`com.sun.media.jfxmedia.AudioClip.create()` (the class used internally by `javafx.scene.media.AudioClip` in Oracle's JFX implementation) offers the ability to create an audio clip from an in-memory byte array. However, as of `java8-b127` it (and the other interesting methods that that class contains, such as `createSegment`) throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The source code doc refer to http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27007 However, it has been deleted from the JIRA. So, don't hold your breath for it to be implemented.