# Jetty and/or Servlet-api in JavaFX breaks deployment

Tags: jetty, javafx-2, javafx, embedded-jetty

I try to embed (use) Jetty **into** my JavaFX 2.2 applet (which runs in a browser).

My problem is that, to host servlets I need to include the servlet-api-3.0.jar also (for javax.servlet namespaces) besides jetty-server.jar, jetty-servlet.jar and jetty-util.jar.

[image]

If I include the servlet-api.jar, my project compiles, but when I run it inside the browser, the deployment fails with the "JavaFX application could not launch due to system configuration (show error details). See java.com/javafx for troubleshooting information." error message.

If I remove the servlet-api.jar (and remove the relevant source) it deploys again.

For the JavaFX project the Java Platform is set to "Default JavaFX Platform", and it would be good to keep it this way to reduce the minimum footprint required.

I'm not a java(fx) expert (I come from .NET world), so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: What are the error details?

Comment: I don't know how to get them, because if I click on the 'show error details' link then the JVM console appears which contains nothing. I don't know how to set this up properly to show errors :/

Comment: Does it work when running as "normal" application (not as an Applet)?

Comment: Yes it does run as a normal app :( If I switch it back to "Run in Browser" it fails again.

Comment: Hm, can you check if the generated JNLP file contains all necessary JARs and that the location of the JARs is correct?

Comment: Yes, under <jnlp><resources> there are all JARs with href="lib/<filename>.jar" size="..." and eager-loading attributes.

Comment: I think you first have to get this error message. It should be in a tab or something on the error dialog, as far as I remember.

Comment: OK, I got the error:
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Could not verify signing in resource: file:/D:/Work/POC/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication1/dist/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar
 at com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.getValidatedJarFile(Unknown Source)

Comment: Are you trying to write some kind of bot?  As I understand it you are trying to write an applet so when users go to your site you start a web server on their PC.  I hope this could never work.

Comment: Andy: take it easy. My applet is a simple sound-Player app. It would download an encrypted sound-byte-array, decrypt it, open it from memory, because I mustn't save it locally. I want to use the javafx-MediaPlayer API, but that only supports urls as input. This is why a local 'webserver' is an approach to provide the in-memory decrypted sound as a local-url.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with signing the JARs. I'm not very familiar with signing JARs for JavaFX but here is the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm#CIAFJGAB

Answer (score 0):

`servlet-api-3.0.jar` is what's known as a *provided* dependency.

It is not needed to be included in your war file, as the web app container (in this case Jetty) provides it for you.  In your build tool, just exclude the servlet-api.jar from being bundled in your war file.

Note: `jetty-server-9.0.0.M5.jar` is also a *provided* dependency and has the same rules.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me: I'm NOT hosting my JavaFX app inside Jetty! I'm hosting my JavaFX app in a static HTML, and I want to use Jetty inside/from the JavaFX app to open an HTTP-listener/servlet inside JavaFX. Or did I misunderstand you? :)